# I want to update OpenSSL with AWS lambda (Python 3.8 runtime)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openssl

**What I want to solve**
I want to update OpenSSL with AWS lambda (Python 3.8 runtime)

**Background**
We are building a serverless web app using the Python 3.8 runtime with AWS lambda.
I want to call the OpenAI API from the official library in the app, but it seems that the urllib used internally must be OpenSSL 1.1.1 or higher to work.

The Python 3.8 runtime seems to have "OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips" by default, and I would like to upgrade to 1.1.1l or the latest. (I have confirmed that it works using an older version of urllib, but I would prefer to upgrade to OpenSSL for security reasons).

**What I have tried**
As for what I tried to upgrade, I know this is an old article, but I tried using the lambda layer method as described in the following article, but it did not reflect the new version and the version remained old.
https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/aws-lambda-openssl/

**Question**
As an AWS newbie, I would appreciate it if any of you experts could enlighten me on any of the following.

・Is it possible to use OpenSSL (usually managed on the OS side) on the lambda layer?
・Is there an alternative?
・Is there any problem with urllib that can be used with 1.0.2k-fips from a security point of view?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you be ok using [Docker images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html)?  That might be the easiest way.  Are you sure that the Lambda uses that SSL version?

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I think using Docker images has the disadvantage of longer deployment time, so I would like to consider this as an option.
I ran the following code in lambda to confirm

`import ssl`
`print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)`